Issues with nested state updates on mutually related objects using Immer.js: changes not reflecting properly
A partner and I are currently working on a side project that aims at creating a React state management library that uses Immer.js to ensure immutability. The end goal is to be able to handle complex graph based state representations. This first attempt aims at developing a simple system where objects can have parent-child relationships, and updates to one side of these relationship are reflected immutably to the other side of the relationship.
State is what a user will be exposed to (now it is limited to an array for simplicity sake, but will in the future be extended to allow any sort of shape), and what we call the idMap is a way for the library to track relationships between entities(this can be seen on the get method of each entity).
Problem
We are encountering an issue where nested updates to the state through entity relationships (parent-child) do not seem to reflect correctly. Specifically, when we update the name of a parent through a child, the change does not propagate as expected.
Code
Below is the implementation of the TestStore class:
import { enableMapSet, immerable, produce, setAutoFreeze } from "immer";
enableMapSet();
setAutoFreeze(false);

export interface iFoo {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  parent?: iFoo | undefined;
  child?: iFoo | undefined;
}

export class TestStore {
  private _state: iFoo[];
  private _idMap: Map<string, any>;
  [immerable] = true;

  constructor() {
    this._state = [];
    this._idMap = new Map();
  }

  newObject(id: string, name: string) {
    const obj = this.createClass(this._idMap);
    const objInstance = new obj({ id, name });
    this._idMap.set(id, objInstance);
    return objInstance;
  }

  produce(f: (draft: any) => void) {
    const newState = produce(this._state, (draft: any) => f(draft));
    this._state = newState;
  }

  createClass(idMap: Map<string, any>) {
    const parent = "parent";
    const child = "child";
    const privateparent = "_parent";
    const privatechild = "_child";

    class Foo implements iFoo {
      _id: string;
      _name: string;
      _parent: string | undefined = undefined;
      _child: string | undefined = undefined;

      constructor(props: { id: string; name: string }) {
        this._id = props.id;
        this._name = props.name;
      }

      get id(): string {
        return this._id;
      }

      get name(): string {
        return this._name;
      }

      set name(value: string) {
        this._name = value;
      }
    }

    Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, "parent", {
      get(): Foo | undefined {
        return this[privateparent] ? idMap.get(this[privateparent]) : undefined;
      },
      set(value: Foo | undefined) {
        const oldvalue = this[parent];
        if (oldvalue) {
          oldvalue[privatechild] = undefined;
        }
        if (value) {
          value[privatechild] = this.id;
          this[privateparent] = value.id;
        } else {
          this[privateparent] = undefined;
        }
      },
      enumerable: true,
    });

    Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, "child", {
      get(): Foo | undefined {
        return this[privatechild] ? idMap.get(this[privatechild]) : undefined;
      },
      set(value: Foo | undefined) {
        const oldvalue = this[child];
        if (oldvalue) {
          oldvalue[privateparent] = undefined;
        }
        if (value !== undefined) {
          this[privatechild] = value.id;
          value[privateparent] = this.id;
        } else {
          this[privatechild] = undefined;
        }
      },
      enumerable: true,
    });

    return Foo;
  }

  getState() {
    return this._state;
  }
}

Tests
The third test case attempts to change the name of a parent through its child's parent property. It currently fails and it is the most important one to test that state is not mutated.
import { iFoo, TestStore } from "./implementation-scenario-3";

let parent: iFoo;
let child: iFoo;
let store: TestStore;

describe("produce only the state", () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    store = new TestStore();
    parent = store.newObject("1", "parent");
    child = store.newObject("2", "child");
  });

  test("Add stuff to state", () => {
    store.produce((draft) => {
      draft.push(parent);
      draft.push(child);
    });
    const state = store.getState();

    expect(state[0]).toBe(parent);
    expect(state[1]).toBe(child);
  });

  test("Add relation between foos", () => {
    store.produce((draft) => {
      draft[1].parent = draft[0];
    });
    const state = store.getState();

    expect(state[0]?.child).toBe(state[1]);
    expect(state[1]?.parent).toBe(state[0]);
  });

  test("change name of the nested parent", () => {
    const initialparent = store.getState()[0];

    store.produce((draft) => {
      draft[1].parent!.name = "new name";
    });
    const state = store.getState();

    expect(state[0].name).toBe("new name");
    expect(state[0]).not.toBe(initialparent);
  });
});


Issue
The third test case does not pass. The parent name is updated through the child's parent property, but it mutates the original idMap element instead of doing it immutably. Immer does not recognise this mutation as data not originated from the state will not be drafted (https://immerjs.github.io/immer/pitfalls/#data-not-originating-from-the-state-will-never-be-drafted).
Research
We have searched for solutions and found similar issues related to Immer and nested updates. We have been working on understanding Immer's pitfalls (https://immerjs.github.io/immer/pitfalls/), but none of the sections have resolved our problem, or we are not being able to understand them in application context.
Question
How can we ensure that nested updates through relationships in our state management system correctly reflect in the state without mutating it? Any help or pointers on what we might be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.
We have spent considerable time debugging this issue and would greatly appreciate any assistance. Thank you in advance!
